# C# infragistics UltraDockManager

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, infragistics

I have created a side tab that opens just fine(basically turned a UltraGrid into a tab, not a form w/ an UltraGrid ), but when pinning the side tab it gets sized in back of the main form.

How do I set the pinned tab layout to open up based on my sizing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the designer, pin the new tab down an resize it, then save the file. Then, unpin it. Infragistics serializes both sizes (pinned and unpinned) in the designer.cs file